# How to delete specific cells with app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-form-quiz

My intention is to be able to delete for example cell F1 without deleting cell F2.

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Questionário DQSA");  
  var range = sheet.getRange("B1:U1");
  range.clearContent();
```

Here I clear the content of these cells but I would like to know how to delete them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Range.deleteCells(Dimension)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deletecellsshiftdimension):

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Questionário DQSA");  
  var range = sheet.getRange("F1");
  range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);//F2 becomes the new F1
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: Its working but what i wanted is that the function wouls never stop deleting the cells if they were empty

Comment: @Bernardo Kindly ask a new question.

Comment: I just did, tks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to roll your own:

```
function deleteCell(shift) {
  var shift=shift || "left"; //left or up
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell=ss.getActiveCell();
  if(shift=="left") {
    var rg=sh.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn());
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var row=vA[0];
    row.splice(cell.getColumn()-1,1);
    rg.clearContent();
    sh.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,row.length).setValues([row]); 
  }
  if(shift=="up") {
    var rg=sh.getRange(1,cell.getColumn(),sh.getLastRow(),1);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var row=vA.map(function(r){return r[0]});
    row.splice(cell.getRow()-1,1);
    var col=[];
    row.forEach(function(e){
      col.push([e]);
    });
    rg.clearContent();
    sh.getRange(1,cell.getColumn(),col.length,1).setValues(col);
  }
}
```

Of course now that I know about that new method in range it's a lot easier to write. Thanks to @TheMaster

```
function deleteCell(shift) {
  var shift=shift || "left";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell=ss.getActiveCell();
  if(shift=="left") {
    cell.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
  }
  if(shift=="up") {
    cell.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
}
```